# How to identify index of substring based on condition

Tags: r, indexing

In this dataframe with speech transcriptions, in column `Turn`, and Part-of-Speech tags, in column `c5`, I want to identify the index of the word `ta` **if** it is *preceded* by the word `got`:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("out tonight ? You 've got ta tell her .",
           "Ta ta Sheila ."),
  c5 = c("AVP AV0 PNP VHB VVN TO0 VVI PNP",
         "ITJ ITJ NP0"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I first split both columns into 'words':

```
library(stringr)
df_test$Turns_split <- lapply(gsub("\\s[.,;:?!]", "", df_test$Turn), function(x) unlist(str_split(x, " ")))
df_test$c5_split <- lapply(df_test$c5, function(x) unlist(str_split(x, " ")))
```

I know how to identify the indices of *any* `ta` (i.e., whether preceded by `got` or not):

```
df_test$Index <-  sapply(df_test$Turns_split, function(x) which(x %in% "ta"))
df_test$Index
[1] 6 2
```

But I want to restrict the result to those instances of `ta` that are immediately preceded by `got`so that the **desired result** is this:

```
df_test$Index
[1] 6
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` over each value of `Turns_split` and get the index where current word is `'ta'` and previous word is `'got'`.

```
sapply(df_test$Turns_split, function(x) which(x == 'ta' & dplyr::lag(x) == 'got')[1])
#[1]  6 NA
```